# Android how do i create an option matrix?

Tags: android

I am creating an android native app in which the user gets several choices of a type of workout they want to do. They can choose intensity, duration and amount of workouts. Each specific combination of choices has a specific outcome. so for instance:

```
choice 1:
a b c
choice 2:
1 2 3
choice 3:
. , /
```

There are 9 possible outcomes in this case. If a user were to select 3 options it would get a specific outcome.

```
a 1 . = outcome 1
a 1 , = outcome 2
a 1 / = outcome 3
a 2 . = outcome 4
etc.
```

I'm wondering what the best way to do this is? I could create an elaborate if/else function but this feels like a bad way to solve this. This feels like it might be a stupid question but I can't come up with anything right now.

Comment: Try appending the user selection to a single string, and than you can use this in a `switch` block with 9 different cases.

Comment: Aren't the total number of outcomes equivalent to 27?

Comment: are all outcomes that originate from A functionally independent from each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I have proposed a rather simple solution to your question. Since I don't know how you plan to implement it in android, I have given a solution in Java.

You need to store your choices as arrays for all the choices.

```
public static final int combination1_length = 2;
public static final int combination2_length = 2;
public static final int combination3_length = 2;

String[] combination1 = new String[combination1_length];
String[] combination2 = new String[combination2_length];
String[] combination3 = new String[combination3_length];

System.out.println("Enter the value of the combinations : ");

System.out.println("Enter values for first array :");
for (int i=0; i<combination1.length; i++) combination1[i] = in.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter values for second array :");
for (int i=0; i<combination2.length; i++) combination2[i] = in.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter values for third array :");
for (int i=0; i<combination3.length; i++) combination3[i] = in.nextLine();
```

Then you need to create an outcome matrix whose dimensions would array_choices1.length * array_choices2.length * ..... * array_choicesN.length.

```
String[][][] outcomes = new String[combination1_length]
    [combination2_length][combination3_length];

System.out.println("Enter outcomes of the combinations :");
    for (int i=0; i<outcomes.length; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<outcomes[0].length; j++)
            for (int k=0; k<outcomes[0][0].length; k++)
                outcomes[i][j][k] = in.nextLine();
```

Then, you need to take the input combination from the user.

```
System.out.println("Enter the combinations preferred : ");
String input1 = in.nextLine();
String input2 = in.nextLine();
String input3 = in.nextLine();
```

Do a choice wise matching from the corresponding arrays and store the index of match from each array of choice.

```
int index1 = 0, index2 = 0, index3 = 0;
for (index1 = 0; index1<combination1.length; index1++)
    if (combination1[index1].equals(input1)) break;
for (index2 = 0; index2<combination2.length; index2++)
    if (combination2[index2].equals(input2)) break;
for (index3 = 0; index3<combination3.length; index3++)
    if (combination3[index3].equals(input3)) break;
```

The outcome would be as follows:

```
System.out.println("The outcome is : " + outcomes[index1][index2][index3]);
```

The complete code is:

```
public static final int combination1_length = 2;
public static final int combination2_length = 2;
public static final int combination3_length = 2;

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] combination1 = new String[combination1_length];
    String[] combination2 = new String[combination2_length];
    String[] combination3 = new String[combination3_length];

    String[][][] outcomes = new String[combination1_length]
    [combination2_length][combination3_length];

    System.out.println("Enter the value of the combinations : ");

    System.out.println("Enter values for first array :");
    for (int i=0; i<combination1.length; i++) combination1[i] = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter values for second array :");
    for (int i=0; i<combination2.length; i++) combination2[i] = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter values for third array :");
    for (int i=0; i<combination3.length; i++) combination3[i] = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter outcomes of the combinations :");
    for (int i=0; i<outcomes.length; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<outcomes[0].length; j++)
            for (int k=0; k<outcomes[0][0].length; k++)
                outcomes[i][j][k] = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter the combinations preferred : ");
    String input1 = in.nextLine();
    String input2 = in.nextLine();
    String input3 = in.nextLine();

    int index1 = 0, index2 = 0, index3 = 0;
    for (index1 = 0; index1<combination1.length; index1++)
        if (combination1[index1].equals(input1)) break;
    for (index2 = 0; index2<combination2.length; index2++)
        if (combination2[index2].equals(input2)) break;
    for (index3 = 0; index3<combination3.length; index3++)
        if (combination3[index3].equals(input3)) break;
    // System.out.println("Index1 : " + index1 + ", Index2 : " + index2 + ", Index3 : " + index3);
    System.out.println("The outcome is : " + outcomes[index1][index2][index3]);
```

I haven't handled boundary cases. Suppose the choice entered by the user is not present in your choice arrays. In that case, appropriate error messages should be displayed. But I guess you would handle that, since you would implement something on the lines of [spinners](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) in android thus eliminating the possibility of an illegal input.